# PhpStorm - <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> - Unexpected token?

Tags: html, css, phpstorm

I have the strangest error with PhpStorm 2017.

I'm working on a simple `.html` file, and when I add some stylesheet links to the `<head>`, PhpStorm says: `Unexpected token ("/")`.

For example there's no such problem with `<script src="/asd/asd/">`

Any help is appreciated.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-writing this line? Sometimes PHPStorm wrongly parses code while you type (for me it's usually with `if (): else: endif;`

Comment: Accidental misconfiguration by the user (typing too fast without looking at what is happing at the  screen). Please show screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: Yes, i've tried without success.

Comment: @LazyOne - https://s2.postimg.org/7k8cbm0p5/image.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your screenshot -- please delete 2 entries that have `IDE` in the last column.

- One of them (top one) creates this issue.
- Second one -- pretty useless (it works like that already). At very least disable this one (if you think it's useful elsewhere or have created it for some other reasons)

[image]

Comment: Indeed - the first one was causing the issue. Thank you!